# Is it Safe to Say That Non-Stationary Series Can Not Be Simulated Using R

Tags: r, arima

I am performing an experiment using classes of `ARIMA` models which I have to simulate for instance `AR`, `MA`, `ARMA` and possibly `ARIMA` using `arima.sim()` function in `R`. I am able to `AR`, `MA`, `ARMA` but `ARIMA` seems impossible as the coefficient of `AR` must be greater than 1 ($|\phi| > 1$) for the series to be non-stationary.

Simulate MA of 10 sample size with a coefficient of 0.8

```
set.seed(837530)
ma1 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ma = c(0.8), order = c(0, 0, 1)), sd = 1)
forecast::auto.arima(ma1, ic = "aicc")
```

Simulate MA of 10 sample size with coefficients of 0.4 and 0.4

```
set.seed(181917)
ma2 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ma = c(0.4, 0.4), order = c(0, 0, 2)), sd = 1)
forecast::auto.arima(ma2, ic = "aicc")
```

Simulate ARMA of 10 sample size with coefficients of 0.4 and 0.4

```
set.seed(455287)
arma11 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = c(0.4), ma = c(0.4), order = c(1, 0, 1)), sd = 1)
forecast::auto.arima(arma11, ic = "aicc")
```

My attempt to simulate from `ARIMA`

```
arima111 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = c(1.1), ma = c(0.3), order = c(1, 1, 1)), sd = 1)
Error in arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = c(1.1), ma = c(0.3), order = c(1,  : 
  'ar' part of model is not stationary
```

**WHAT I WANT**

1. Can it be said in a public domain that `it is not possible to simulate a series from ARIMA distribution`? (having $\phi$ value as the estimate of `AR` parameter and $\theta$ asthe estimate of `MA parameter).
2. If it is possible, please demonstrate it for me using `arima.sim()` function or through any other way using `R`.

Comment: Any time series with a trend is non-stationary.

Comment: It's possible to simulate anything in R. Some built in functions aren't able to do everything but with the language itself you can achieve whatever you want.

Answer (score 4):

It *is* possible to simulate a nonstationary process using `arima.sim`. From `?arima`:

> For ARIMA models with differencing, the differenced series follows a zero-mean ARMA model.

Hence, in the call `arima.sim(model = list(order, ar, ma), n)` with `order = c(p, d, q)`, `ar` and `ma` specify parameters of an ARMA(p, q) model for a `d`-order differenced time series, *not* an undifferenced time series.

Stationarity of the the differenced time series is enforced with the following constraint on `ar`, which you can find in the body of `arima.sim`:

```r
    p <- length(model$ar)
    if (p) {
        minroots <- min(Mod(polyroot(c(1, -model$ar))))
        if (minroots <= 1) 
            stop("'ar' part of model is not stationary")
    }
```

In other words, the roots of the polynomial whose coefficients are `c(1, -ar)` are required to lie outside of the unit circle. (The very same constraint is stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model).)

Stationarity of the differenced time series *does not* imply stationarity of the undifferenced time series. In fact, the undifferenced time series is never stationary. `?arima.sim` gives an example:

```r
ts.sim <- arima.sim(list(order = c(1, 1, 0), ar = 0.7), n = 200)
ts.plot(ts.sim)
```

But it is better to compare collections of simulations:

```r
set.seed(1L)
X <- replicate(50L, arima.sim(list(order = c(1, 0, 0), ar = 0.7), n = 200))
Y <- replicate(50L, arima.sim(list(order = c(1, 1, 0), ar = 0.7), n = 200))

par(mfrow = c(1L, 2L))
matplot(X, type = "l", main = "AR(1) = ARIMA(1, 0, 0)")
matplot(Y, type = "l", main = "ARIMA(1, 1, 0)")
```

[image]

If you insist on *p*-values, then you can perform [Dickey-Fuller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test) tests:

```r
apply(X, 2L, function(x) tseries::adf.test(x, k = 0)$p.value)
##  [1] 0.9263981 0.9900000 0.9900000 0.2561765 0.9218488
##  [6] 0.9900000 0.1816286 0.9900000 0.9900000 0.9372659
## [11] 0.6991314 0.9018098 0.8618604 0.9390623 0.6203794
## [16] 0.9740316 0.9002020 0.8196272 0.6657746 0.9593784
## [21] 0.9900000 0.9900000 0.8572043 0.1337945 0.9817778
## [26] 0.9900000 0.9900000 0.9816193 0.9562682 0.9900000
## [31] 0.4298187 0.9550181 0.7608263 0.9900000 0.9455187
## [36] 0.7616230 0.9412379 0.9588200 0.9354637 0.9900000
## [41] 0.9900000 0.9628406 0.9818668 0.9203677 0.9804385
## [46] 0.9900000 0.9900000 0.9807893 0.9048136 0.9822757

apply(X, 2L, function(x) tseries::adf.test(diff(x), k = 0)$p.value)
##  [1] 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01
## [11] 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01
## [21] 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01
## [31] 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01
## [41] 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01

apply(Y, 2L, function(x) tseries::adf.test(x, k = 0)$p.value)
##  [1] 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01
## [11] 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01
## [21] 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01
## [31] 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01
## [41] 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01
```

(These *p*-values are computed by linear interpolation on a *very* coarse grid. You should take 0.01 to mean some number between 0 and 0.01, and 0.99 to mean some number between 0.99 and 1.)

Comment: stationary comes to play when $|\phi| > 1$ and not when $d = 1$. use tseries::adf() function to check the stationary status of your series and tell me the outcome.